# Android Studio Win7 Sp1 error adb.exe on start Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

On my PC Android Studio  Win7 Sp1 i have error adb.exe on start Emulator.
Error in log :
Bug in AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Bu module: C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll

But If I use real phone - it's work. Or  PC  Windows 8 it's  work.

What is it?

Comment: May be this is a windows error. Try this link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/how-to-fix-ntdlldll-error/9e455b5a-cc9d-4724-9eb1-ecbd755366b2

Comment: But, if i use phone with usb it' work...

Comment: Because while using phone you only need adb drivers to execute your code but while using emulator a virtual device is created & that is created & controlled completly in OS dependent environment.

Comment: Today I install VirtualBox with Android and  ))  It's work. Vary strange situation.... with Android Studion Emulator on my windows

Comment: did you use the same windows os?

Comment: Yes, I use the same Windows 7 x64 Sp1 and the same PC

Answer (score 0):

[You could try the instructions in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TciqC.png)

Comment: why do you post text as a picture? Better write down the solution here in the answer and provide a link to the source of the information.

Comment: Ops, I done all steps in you help, but its not work too.  On start of emulator many copyes of adb.exe  is crashed. Why?